# clearing google map by second click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google map for my project. When user click map I show a marker. How can I clear the map and show another marker by the second click?

```
                function myMap() {
                    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
                    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(32.1788385, 54.5177581);
                    var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 5};
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                        placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
                    });
                }

                function placeMarker(map, location) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        map: map
                    });
                }
```

Comment: See `marker.setMap(null)` method.

Comment: @AdamAzad Where I have to use? it doesn't work in `google.maps.event.addListener`

Comment: I think you have to change your structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the reference of the marker in a global variable. You would also need to either check the type of `marker` or wrap it in `try-catch` statement.

```
const mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var marker;

function initMap(){

    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(32.1788385, 54.5177581);
    var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 5};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
    });
}

function placeMarker(map, location) {

    // Remove the previous marker
    try {
        marker.setMap(null)
    } catch (e) {}

    // Update the marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });

}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/od5uf46x/)

Comment: Call `placeMarker` after the map is initiated. That will set the default marker.